# Find maximum data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have this kind of table and find the maximum mark

STUDENT

```
|id | name  | mark |
|1  | john  | 56   |
|2  | sara  | 81   |
|3  | mattew| 65   |
```

the out suppose to be like this

```
|id | name  | mark |
|2  | sara  | 81   |
```

but i get this kind of output

```
|id | name  | mark |
|1  | john  | 81   |
```

i write this in sql

```
SELECT id,name,MAX(mark)
FROM student;
WHERE name IN
(SELECT name
FROM student);
```

how can i correct the sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM student
WHERE mark IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mark DESC
```

Though you could also use the logically equivalent standard SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM   student
WHERE  mark = (SELECT MAX(mark)
               FROM   student)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple query to get same result:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID,NAME,mark 
    FROM STUDENT
    ORDER BY MARK DESC
```